# The meaning of “out from”

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, phrases

When I was learning English by watching CNN news, I saw a news with the title “ *The polls show Biden is a clear favorite 100 days out from an unprecedented election*”, I want to know that is “out from” a phrase here. And if it is, what’s the meaning of it.

Comment: In this context 'out from' means 'away from in time, before'.

Comment: But why I can’t find this phrase in the dictionary?

Comment: It is a fairly new idiomatic usage and dictionaries often lag behind usage. See discussion [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/177851/from-4-years-out-meaning) about the use of 'out' to mean 'distant in time'.

Answer (score 2):

"Out from" is another way of saying "away from." I hear people say "away from" more often than "out from," and "away from" is the more formal way of saying it. You could say "*The polls show Biden is a clear favorite 100 days **away** from an unprecedented election*." You could even say "*The polls show Biden is a clear favorite 100 days from an unprecedented election*." The word "out" or "away" is unnecessary in this case, but there is nothing wrong with using "away from" or "out from." In more formal writing, use "away from" instead of "out from."

Comment: I think formal writing would use _before_. _out from_ can literally mean _away from_, as in "6 days out from Chicago the whole wagon train got dissentary." I think both phrases are just fun ways to mix it up when talking about an upcoming event.

Answer (score 1):

Time may be referred to as if it were a physical location. For instance, we may ask *where* something happens in a movie, rather than *when*. This may come from books, where time is more obviously physical (which page you’re on).

- The election is 100 days in the future.

Means the same as:

- The election is 100 days out (or away).

The assumed reference point is now or here unless stated otherwise.

In your example, the author is counting down the days until the election, a fixed reference point in time, so this is inverted: we are now 100 days out (or away) from the election.